# node.js stripe UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning while making query

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

```
(node:26431) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Stripe: Unknown arguments ([object Object]). Did you mean to pass an options object? See https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/wiki/Passing-Options. (on API request to POST `/charges`)
    at getRequestOpts (/home/fractaluser/Desktop/upwork/dylan/facebook_marketing/marketing_backend/node_modules/stripe/lib/makeRequest.js:37:11)
    at /home/fractaluser/Desktop/upwork/dylan/facebook_marketing/marketing_backend/node_modules/stripe/lib/makeRequest.js:68:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at makeRequest (/home/fractaluser/Desktop/upwork/dylan/facebook_marketing/marketing_backend/node_modules/stripe/lib/makeRequest.js:66:10)
    at Constructor.create (/home/fractaluser/Desktop/upwork/dylan/facebook_marketing/marketing_backend/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeMethod.js:31:7)
    at /home/fractaluser/Desktop/upwork/dylan/facebook_marketing/marketing_backend/server.js:50:20
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:26431) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:26431) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.




app.post("/payment", (req, res) => {
  const { product, token } = req.body;
  const { idempontencyKey } =product.idempontencyKey;
  return stripe.customers.create({
    email: token.email,
    source: token.id
  }).then(customer => {
    stripe.charges.create({
      amount: product.price * 100,
      currency: "usd",
      customer: customer.id,
      receipt_email: token.email,
      description: product.name,
      shipping: {
        name: token.card.name,
        address: {
          country: token.card.address_country
        }
      }
    }, {idempontencyKey})
  })
  .then(result => res.status(200).json(result))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

Here i am trying to integrate and make payment(test mode) using stripe from node.js
But, while making query i am getting above error.

The error is proplely undestandable for me

Please have a look where i am making the mistake

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the docs were incorrect here, the key name for the idempotency key is actually `idempotency_key` not `idempotencyKey`.

The second argument passed to Charge create to be the following?

`{ idempotency_key: idempotencyKey }`